# generate html or excel or pdf document for mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a database schema and i want to generate a document in any format(html or pdf or excel) of all the tables,stored procedures ,triggers for mysql .Please suggest a suitable tool which can provide all the documents

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps should help:

1. connect to the database and retrieve data
2. use an appropriate module in your programming language of choice which is able to handle formats such as HTML/PDF/XLS(X)
3. organise the retrieved data in a presentable form and write to file using the module that you chose in step 2

Comment: Thanks Alan,i want a tool or utility which can dynamically generate these docs for me.